# Can we apply Markov in the opposite direction?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Obviously, Markov is commonly used for finding the probability that a random variable is greater than some constant times the mean, with $c>1$:
$$
Pr[X \geq c \cdot E[X]] \leq \frac{1}{c}
$$

But how can it be applied in the opposite direction? In other words, is there a way to manipulate Markov to get some expression for
$$
Pr[X \leq c \cdot E[X]]
$$
where $c < 1$?

Comment: Just use $P(A) = 1-P(A^\complement).$ So $P(X \leq c \mu) = 1 - P(X \geq c \mu) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{c}.$ (This assumes $X$ is positive.)

Comment: @WilliamM. This approach only works when $c > 1$, but I'm looking for an approach where basically we are finding the probability that $X$ is less than some fraction of the mean

Comment: Since it is possible to have $X$ always equal to the mean, when $0\le c <1$ you get left with $0 \le \Pr[X \leq c \cdot E[X]]\lt 1$. These are the best you can do when all you know is the mean since you can achieve $0$ and get arbitrarily close to $1$